# Awk show x by not y

Tags: sed, awk

Is it possible to combine these in one line to be alittle more efficent.

```
awk '$4 ~/^[x]/' raw.txt > x_raw.txt
awk '!/y/' x_raw.txt > xy_raw.txt
```

Is this possible with maybe perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to switch to perl to do logical AND just use the operator `&&`. The following prints the lines where the fourth field starts with `x` and the line doesn't contain `y`:

```
awk '$4~/^x/&&!/y/' raw.txt > xy_raw.txt
```

Comment: The performance can also depend on the order of these checks, if the number of lines containing `y` are less than the lines containing `x` in the 4th column then reverse them.